# apache virtual host to work with django

Tags: django, apache, virtualhost

My project is under: /home/projects/testing and I'm adding this to the buttom of my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file on Centos machine, but that is not working,

```
<Location "/testing/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE testing.settings
    PythonOption django.root /testing
    PythonDebug On
    PythonPath "['/home/projects/'] + sys.path"
</Location>
```

but when requesting http://localhost/testing/jobs for example, I get:

```
Mod_python error: "PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython"

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line 299, in HandlerDispatch
    result = object(req)

.............

 File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.4.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 75, in __init__
    raise ImportError, "Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)

ImportError: Could not import settings 'testing.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named testing.settings
```

Answer (score 3):

You want both, the projects folder and the testing folder in your PythonPath, because  your project uses paths without the "testing" in it:

```
PythonPath "['/home/projects/', '/home/projects/testing/'] + sys.path"
```

Comment: updated the PythonPath as instructed, and made the settings directly on settings file inside the project. Still no luck.

Comment: @reko_t: the traceback says "import error", "no module named testing.settings". Assuming that the files `/home/projects/testing/__init__.py` and `/home/projects/testing/settings.py` exist, the `/home/projects` on the path should suffice. This is why I'd say it was more likely that mod_python can't read the files, rather than can't find them.

Comment: If `/home/projects/testing/__init__.py` doesn't exist, then importing `testing.settings` will fail.  I'd suggest making your python path as @reko_t suggested, but then use:  `SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE settings`.  This should work weather `__init__.py` exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

The path looks okay to me, I've just double checked that items in `sys.path` work with trailing slashes.

I'd suggest that this is a file permissions issue:

- Does the user apache is running under have access to the project files?
- Is selinux preventing access?

Comment: made the folder with permission 777, I'm using Centos as well, there is no selinux AFAIK. Still no luck.

Comment: I've not had any exposure to Centos, but the existence of this document, http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/rhlcommon-chapter-0017.html would lead me to believe that Centos doesn't intrinsically lack selinux.